# Unable to start Netbeans 7.2 Profiler for Java ME projects

Tags: netbeans, java-me, profiler, netbeans-7.2

I'm trying to figure out why my Java ME app (a media player) is throwing Out of Memory Exceptions,however I have been unable to start the Netbeans profiler.The profiler works fine for other project types but is grayed out when I select any Java ME projects.
I tried to start it by invoking the emulator at the command prompt and supplying appropriate arguments(Xprofile to start cpu profiler and Xnetmon to start network monitor) but the emulator started without the profiling tools.

Next,I tried re-installing Netbeans hoping that would clear any configurations issues I might have ran into but still no luck.

Environment:
I'm using Windows 7 64bit with  JDK version  1.7.0_04 and Netbeans 7.2  which comes with Java ME SDK 3.0.5 and I've installed Java SDK tools.

Other Info: 
When I select the unintegrate profiler from project(under Advanced Commands under the Profile Menu) I get a message that it is not integrated in the first place but I have no idea how trigger this integration. When I select the calibrate profiler option I only see JDK 1.& platform and none of my Java Me Platforms.

I am not sure what the profiler is dependent on or of the quirks of Netbeans so  I may not have provided enough information any pointers for more relevant information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While searching for another answer I came across this question. The problem here is no J2ME platform is integrated with the IDE. The way to add a platform is : on Tools menu --> click "Java Platforms" --> click "Add Platforms..." button --> on the add platform wizard click "Java ME CLDC Platform Emulator" (2nd option) --> click "Next" --> browse and select location of your J2ME platform --> finish the add process. After restarting netbeans IDE the profiler will now be activated.